# Get the list of post categories

Tags: php, categories

How to get the list of post categories I have this but it returns only one category and the entire list?

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo 'term_id) . '">'  .$category->name .$category->term_id.  '';
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get just the categories the current post is in?

Comment: yes, i want to get category list

Answer (score 0):

To get categories assigned to the current post, use [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/).

`get_categories()` is designed to get a list of all categories on the site.